# How Do I Grab a div with the most Tags via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to search through my HTML code via jQuery to get the div with the most HTML tags. In the example below, jQuery should return #div2 because it contains 4 divs inside it.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this example is a bit ambiguous - I didn't think a very specific block of code was necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would do it...but maybe it's because the time is 11 pm here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it by `iterating through each div` and `keeping the div with maximum childs`,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WhXK8/)**

```
maxChild = 0;
maxChildDiv = null;

$('div').each(function(){
    currentChildCount = $(this).children().length 
    if(currentChildCount > maxChild ) 
    {
        maxChild = currentChildCount ;
        maxChildDiv = $(this);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it into my source code soon and see if it works properly

Comment: This will work if you like to have the id you can use the attr as you required i.e.,

alert($(maxChildDiv ).attr("id"))

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    max = 0;
    divid = null;

    $('div').each(function() {
        if($(this).children().length > max) {
            max = $(this).children().length;
            divid = $(this).attr('id');
        } 
    });

    alert (divid);
});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
        </div>
        <div id="div3">
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var maxDiv = $('div').get().reduce(function(child1, child2) {
  return $(child1).children().length > $(child2).children().length ? child1 : child2;
});
alert(maxDiv.id);
```

The `reduce` method is [part of ECMAScript 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so it is supported by modern browsers (more efficiently). You can add `reduce` to the `Array` prototype if it doesn't exist, as described in that link.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/KbsYe/16/).